# How to properly rename a worksheet after adding as a new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, rename, worksheet

I would like to rename my worksheet but its not working.
I can't seem to find the answer similar to my case yet.
Here is my code

```
dim shNew as worksheet

set shNew = Sheets(3).copy(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
shNew.name = Sheets(2).cells(1,2)
```

The code can run without any error but the name remain unchange for the new sheet.

Comment: "The code can run without any error" - no it does not?  The `Worksheet.Copy` method doesn't have a return value, so you can't `Set shNew` in that line.  Perform the copy and then `set shNew = Sheets(Sheets.Count))`    If you're not seeing any error because you've used `On Error resume Next` then you should study up on what that does: it just ignores any errors and you'll never find out your code is bad.

Comment: It just like run through the line but did nothing.

Comment: Oh...I kinda get it now....
As my set shnew is not retuning a value but just doing what I told it to.
So it cant rename a 'nothing'
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes since there's no return value there's nothing to rename.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Sheets(3).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly but I want the new sheet as a worksheet variable.
I have the answer to my question from @Tim Wiliiams already.
Since I only told 'set' to add a new sheet for me. Not declaring a worksheet to the shNew.
That is why it cant rename as shNew is nothing just a command to add new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer already thanks to @Tim Williams.
As I only told shNew to add a new sheet for me, so shNew is just a command of adding a new sheet thus no value returned.
With no value to 'rename', it did nothing for the rename line.